# "Test Framework" part does not appear when creating new project

Tags: unit-testing, intellij-idea

I saw in a training series video that the field for choosing which framework to write unit tests with later in the project does not appear in my Intellij idea. The other parts are the same, but I don't have the part I circled. How will I bring this part?

I know it is not recommended to add a photo, but I felt the need to add it to explain exactly where the problem is.

[image: IntelliJ Idea New Project Screen]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New project wizard was revamped since 2022.1, and "Test framework" was removed on purpose, see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-288286

This guide https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-running-your-first-java-ee-application.html#new_project should reflect most recent changes. You can leave a feedback for a page if any info is still outdated